# Tensorflow Dataset issue at inference phase

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I created a *char-level language generation* with Tensorflow [here](https://github.com/hadifar/tensorflow-starter/tree/master/lesson7). I used `tf.placeholder` API, which according to the [google docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data):

> **Feeding** is least efficient way to feed data into a TensorFlow program.

I decided to change my code and replace it with new TensroFlow [Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets).

I used [from_generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) to create Dataset:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, (tf.int32, tf.int32),
                                             (tf.TensorShape([None, None]),
                                              tf.TensorShape([None, None])))
self.iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
self.inp, self.target = self.iterator.get_next()
```

As can be seen in above code, I used `[None, None]` for `Tensorshape` to give the model more generality. During the training everything is perfectly fine. **But at inference some problem arise**. In `tf.placeholder` API I used following code to generate characters:

```
def inference(self):
    converter = utils.TextReader(filename=FLAGS.CONVERTER_PATH)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        samples = []
        new_state = sess.run(self.init_state)
        c = 12 # random starting token
        samples.append(c)

        for i in range(1000):
            x = np.zeros((1, 1))
            x[0, 0] = c
            feed_dict = {
                self.inp: x,
                self.init_state: new_state
            }
            preds, new_state = sess.run([self.prediction, self.final_state], feed_dict=feed_dict)
            c = utils.pick_top_n(preds, converter.vocab_size)
            samples.append(c)

        samples = np.array(samples)
        print(converter.arr_to_text(samples))
```

In Dataset API, I dont have `tf.placeholder` to feed my previous character. And when I use the above code, as expected, following error happened:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,50] vs. shape[1] = [32,50]
```

At inference, the model use the same input shape (`[32,50]`) that I used for training. Which is not what I want (Actually, I define TensorShape([None,None]) to handle this but not works).

How can I fix the issue with new Dataset API?

[Complete code](https://github.com/hadifar/tensorflow-starter/tree/master/lesson9).